# How to handle special character in nsxmlparser?

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

When i try to parse the company list from webservice which is not parsing properly since company name have trademark symbol (c) as a symbol instead of htmlentities. can you tell me how to resolve special character related issue in objective-c using NSXmlparser

Thanks in advance - sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CDATA tags to enclose the content in your XML